# How to get maximum value from rows, only from specific columns

Tags: google-sheets, microsoft-excel

My sheet looks something like this:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1IbHLts4V4hyc2bo_TfgZzZhFiMXkD5FSlPlpSm7xloY/edit?usp=sharing

[image]

How would I make a formula for the max/min columns, to get the maximum/minimum value for each row, but only including columns that have the value "bar"? (highlighted in green for clarity)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need following formulas: [MAXIFS](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/7013817?hl=en-GB) and [MINIFS](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/7014063?hl=en-GB).

```
=MAXIFS(A2:G2,$A1:$G1,"bar")
=MINIFS(A2:G2,$A1:$G1,"bar")
```